# Android ListView not visible correctly when Click on button

Tags: android, list, sqlite, android-alertdialog

On click to the button ,a List is opened . And on further list items there is cancel button which will delete that row from list as well as from database . On the list view button an alert dialog will appear but after setting all this my click on the button for displaying a list is not working. what can be the reason behind it? where I have been doing wrong?

Button which is opening a list :-

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {

        list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
});
```

onClick of Listview button:-

```
 holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(final View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                adb.setTitle("Delete?");
                adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ");
                final int user_id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                adb.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {

                        SendJobDataBase dBHandler = new SendJobDataBase(
                            activity.getApplicationContext());
                       dBHandler.Delete_Contact(user_id);
                      onResume();

                    }
                    });    


                adb.show();
```

Comment: list is not working..What does that mean?

Comment: it means that list items are not shown when i click at the button.

Comment: Please post the listview code.

Comment: use adapter because it provides better feasibility...

Comment: ListItems are displayed successfully if I am not applying AlertDialog on the button in the list item .

Comment: I am using adapter but problem is somewhere applying alert dialog to the button in list item.

Comment: @user3467204 Can you confirm that the problem is not in dialog, but in the fact that your `showListButton` onClick is not called when you have set `onClick` for list row's buttons ?

Comment: when i put the code for alert dialog within comments , it works fine. So , it seems to me that problem is somewhere in the dialog.

Comment: @user3467204 so, it works fine if you set empty `onClick` listener for your list buttons ?

Comment: @kiruwka actually I haven't post whole code here.

Comment: @user3467204 Could you please post your `onClick` listener for in-list buttons ?

Comment: @user3467204 Your code is working fine for me. You will have to provide code of how you create your list and where your button is located. Important : remove `onResume` call from your `AlertDialog#onClickListener` !!!

Comment: what happens if you change your code to `holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(final View v) { /*empty*/ }});`